# Why am I getting the ReSharper error "The extracted code has multiple entry points"?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, refactoring, resharper

I am using the ReSharper to re-factor my code. When I try to move a block of code to the method, I get the following warning:

`The extracted code has multiple entry points`

Here is the method signature I am planning to use:

```
private void GetRatePlanComponents(ProductPlan productPlan, 
    ProductRatePlan productRatePlan)
```

I searched the web to understand what does it mean. But didn't have much luck. Would someone explain it?

For your reference, here is the code snippet I am trying to move to a separate method:

```
QueryResult productRatePlanChargeQueryResult = 
    _zuoraService.query(string.Format(@"select Id, Name, IncludedUnits from
        ProductRatePlanCharge where ProductRatePlanId = '{0}' and 
        ChargeModel = 'Overage Pricing'", productRatePlan.Id));

if (productRatePlanChargeQueryResult.size > 0)
{
    foreach (ProductRatePlanCharge productRatePlanCharge 
        in productRatePlanChargeQueryResult.records)
    {
        string numberOfUnits = productRatePlanCharge.IncludedUnits.ToString();

        if (productRatePlanCharge.Name.Equals("Users"))
        {
            productPlan.NumberofUsers = numberOfUnits;
        }
        else if (productRatePlanCharge.Name.Equals("Projects"))
        {
            productPlan.NumberofProjects = numberOfUnits;
        }
        else if (productRatePlanCharge.Name.Equals("Storage"))
        {
            decimal volumeOfStorage;
            if (decimal.TryParse(productRatePlanCharge.IncludedUnits.ToString(), 
                out volumeOfStorage))
            {
                if (volumeOfStorage < 1) volumeOfStorage *= 1000;
                    productPlan.VolumeofStorage = volumeOfStorage.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    productPlan.VolumeofStorage = numberOfUnits;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it says multiple *entry* points rather than *exit* points? Does it point at a particular line? Is that the entirety of the method? Can you include the method signature?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes. it says "entry point". Have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you may have encountered [a known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-264378):

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<ITagPrefixHolder> GetRelevantHolders(IPsiSourceFile sourceFile )
> {
>   var targetPath = FileSystemPath.Empty;
>   var projectFile = sourceFile.ToProjectFile();
>   if (projectFile != null)
>     targetPath = projectFile.Location;
>
>   foreach(var holder in GetRelevantHoldersBeforeFile(sourceFile, targetPath))
>     yield return holder;
>
>   foreach(var holder in GetHoldersInFile(sourceFile, targetPath))
>     yield return holder;
> }
> ```

Select both foreach-loops and extract method. It gives strange warning
that the fragment has multiple entry points (??!) and results in the
following code:

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<ITagPrefixHolder> GetRelevantHolders(IPsiSourceFile sourceFile )
> {
>   var targetPath = FileSystemPath.Empty;
>   var projectFile = sourceFile.ToProjectFile();
>   if (projectFile != null)
>     targetPath = projectFile.Location;
>
>   foreach(var tagPrefixHolder in Foo(sourceFile, targetPath))
>        yield return tagPrefixHolder;
> }
>
> private static IEnumerable<ITagPrefixHolder> Foo(IPsiSourceFile sourceFile, FileSystemPath targetPath)
> {
>   foreach(var holder in GetRelevantHoldersBeforeFile(sourceFile, targetPath))
>     yield return holder;
>   foreach(var holder in GetHoldersInFile(sourceFile, targetPath))
>     yield return holder;
> }
> ```

It would be better to replace generated foreach with simple `return
Foo(sourceFile, targetPath);`.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen ReSharper do this same thing when the code I was trying to extract had a couple of throw statements.

You can do what I did in that case--systematically comment out one line at a time until you find the one that ReSharper trips over. Then you can extract the method and uncomment the line afterwards.

Or you can just refactor it by hand.